# Securing HTML contents from servers of same origin

Tags: security, encryption, privacy

It's not a common question, but I wonder if any tricks or upcoming standards exist.

Belows are a flow and what I want to implement.

1. Web application loaded from server-side
2. Client-side script loads some secure contents (not from #1) that need to be protected from web application provider. It could be shown to a user visually.
3. Web application provider knows where are the secure contents (in Dom path) and possibly may try to catch it by putting a script
4. However the secure contents shouldn't be hijacked from servers (even from the same origin) or from external application (even from developer tools if possible)

EDIT:

For better understanding, it's for use case where web application doesn't hold user data in their DB but loads the data from somewhere else. In case, I need to protect the data from web application, which is uncommon in regular web application.

Comment: Use iframes and set SCP?

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Common use case is to protect from xss but not from same origin. If my web app domain is www.wantyourdata.com, can the iframe with SCP protect data from scripts in www.wantyourdata.com?

Comment: Nope. You should isolate using a different subdomain.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, I need an opposite.
https://jsfiddle.net/fkiller/410928bc/1/
This example, web application only capture contents from the same domain iframe (/robot.txt) whereas it can't capture cross-domain iframe (//google.com/robot.txt). However, you can enable it by set X-Frame-Options to ```allow-from https://google.com``` and it is from web server, which means that web application has a control to access the information. My intention is not to give web application such a control. Consider this is more like a platform provided to web application providers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a content security policy (CSP) which would enable the browser to deny injection attacks. These can be a little tricky to setup correctly so I would use [Report URI](https://report-uri.com/) to help you get it going. The trick is to use report only mode first until you have validated the settings then switch to enforce.